# How to display the data contained in Django models in a Django Dropdown menu form?

Tags: django, python-3.x

Currently, I have some data stored in a Django model with the following structure:

```
#Django model
from django.db import models

class Customer(models.Model):
    first_name = models.Charfield(max_length = 120, null = False, blank = False)
    last_name = models.Charfield(max_length = 120, null = False, blank = False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.first_name+ " " + self.last_name
```

I want to display all the customers that are stored in the Customer model in the DropDown menu form. What I tried was the following but I've got no success:

```
#Django form
from .models import Customer

# This throws as a result <Django.db.models.query.utils.deferred.attribute at 0x00013F> inside of the DropDown Menu form
class DropDownMenuCustomer(forms.Form):
    Customer = forms.ChoiceField(choices=[(x,x) for x in str(Customer.first_name)+str(" ")+ str(Customer.last_name))])
```

Another possibility without success was:

```
#Django form
from .models import Customer

class DropDownMenuCustomer(forms.Form):
    querySet = Customer.objects.all()
    list_of_customers = []
    for customer in querySet:
        list_of_customers.append(customer.first_name + " " + customer.last_name)

    customer= forms.ChoiceField(choices=[(x) for x in list_of_customers)])
```

This last possibility does not find list_of_customers, just as if the variable has not been declared. How can I display the data stored in the Django models in the Django forms?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to write it differently. To get all the customer names you'll have to define it in its own function. That way you can generate the choices that way.

```
def customer_names():
    list_of_customers = []
    querySet = Customer.objects.all()
    for customer in querySet:
        list_of_customers.append(customer.first_name + " " + customer.last_name)
    return list_of_customers


class DropDownMenuCustomer(forms.Form):

    customer= forms.ChoiceField(choices=[(x) for x in customer_names())])
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `forms.ModelChoiceField` is much more better like:

```
customer = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Customer.objects.all(), empty_label="(Nothing)")
```

[More information](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/forms/fields/#modelchoicefield)